# About .ind and .idx

Tags: makeindex

I do not know why after creating the file `.idx`, LaTeX does not create the file `.ind`. I am using the following commands:

In the preamble

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

at the end

```
\printindex
```

Comment: Welcome. // Did you run the command line and compile Latex again?

Comment: We need more context here. Can you provide a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile as see exactly what the issue is? Can you do that?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_01}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_02}
\printindex
\end{document}

Comment: @CarlosBasterodeEleizalde: For future reference, you should really read this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Say, your latex code is stored in myDoc.tex . It contains the statements you mentioned.

Compile Latex for the first time.

Open a terminal (i.e. cmd on windows), set the path to the directory of myDoc.tex and run from the command line, where `>` denotes the prompt:

```
> makeindex myDoc
```

This step compiles all relevant info from your `\index{}` statements made.

Compile Latex a second time, and there you go.

See the manual of `package makeidx` for more details: https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf